# Vert.x verticals approach

Tags: java, api, vert.x

Wanted to understand the approach we should follow if we have to build multiple (three in my case) APIs in Vert.x

Should we have separate verticals running for each API i.e. Have a master verticle, and three verticles for each of these. Master verticle sends message to each verticle and that verticle takes care of formulating message and send it back

OR

Have a single verticle, just route it to separate methods with method calls

Please suggest how we should decide on the approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your 1st option is not so good, because usually you don't need master verticle for load balancing inside VM. Read [Scaling - sharing TCP servers](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_scaling_sharing_tcp_servers) section.

You can run all APIs in one verticle or one API per one verticle. 1st option is easy to scale inside 1 VM (read URL above), but 2nd option is more flexible for scalability across multiple servers and development, however it requires load balancer (you can use nginx or HAProxy).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @berserkk. Keep it in one verticle, otherwise different parts of the API would have to run on different ports - as you cannot create multiple HTTP servers in multiple verticles listening on the same port.

However, a good way to split up your API might be based on vert.x `Routers`. Let's assume you have API submodules structured like this

```
/products/...
/inventory/...
/orders/...
```

For every of these submodules you can create a `Router` provider, e.g. `ProductsRouterProvider`, `InventoryRouterProvider` or `OrdersRouterProvider`.

Each of these providers takes care of the specific API module - basically registers required routes.

```java
class ProductsRouterProvider {
  static Router create(Vertx vertx) {
    Router router = Router.router(vertx)
    router.get("/").handler(new ListAllProductsHandler())
    router.get("/:productId").handler(new ProductDetailHandler())
    ...
    return router;
  }
}
```

And finally, register the submodule `Routers` on the base `Router`.

```java
Router router = Router.router(vertx)
router.mountSubRouter("/", ProductsRouterProvider.create(vertx))
router.mountSubRouter("/", InventoryRouterProvider.create(vertx))
router.mountSubRouter("/", OrdersRouterProvider.create(vertx))
```